# Eager load scoped set of objects in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem similar to this one, only with a newer version of rails:

[Ruby on Rails - Add condition on ':include =>' to load limited number of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454204/ruby-on-rails-add-condition-on-include-to-load-limited-number-of-objects)

I'd like to eager load an association, but scope what's included in the eager load. Is this possible in rails 3.2? I've tried

```
Foo.includes(:bar).where("bars.col = x")
```

But that restricts to only `Foo`'s which have at least one `Bar` where `col = x`, while I want also those `Foo`'s with no `Bar`'s.  I could create another association, but then I lose the ability to send in arguments (doesn't seem like :conditions can handle a lambda with arguments).

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I think this other question of mine might be more precisely what you're looking for @user1158559: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691558/refining-the-inner-join-when-using-includes-in-activerecord. I asked it after learning a bunch more about rails. It's also unanswered

Comment: You're right. Might have to blow another 50 rep on that one! Thankyou!

Comment: I added a bounty to my other (IMO better) question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to include needed Foo's in scope with next

```
Foo.includes(:bar).where("bars.col = x OR bars.id IS NULL")
```

or

```
Foo.includes(:bar).where("bars.col = x AND bars.id IS NULL")
```

depends on your needs

so you may do it dynamically , something like

```
#Foo class
def self.including_bars_equal_to(x) # or scope :including_bars_equal_to, :lambda{|x| ....}
   self.includes(:bar).where("bars.col = ? AND bars.id IS NULL", x)  
end
```

**Attempt2**
maybe you should try custom join together with include

```
Foo.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN bars ON foos.id = bars.foo_id AND bars.col = 'x'").
includes(:bar)
```

or you can combine joins with select select

```
  Foo.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN bars ON foos.id = bars.foo_id AND bars.col = 'x'").
  select("foos.*, bar.id as bar_id, bar.col as bar_col")
```

Comment: Good answer, but not quite. This will generate `SELECT foos.*, bars.* FROM foos LEFT OUTER JOIN bars ON bars.foo_id = foos.id WHERE bars.col = x OR bars.id IS NULL`, whereas I want `SELECT foos.*, bars.* FROM foos LEFT OUTER JOIN bars ON bars.foo_id = foos.id AND bars.col = x`. The difference is that your query won't return rows for `foo`s that have a `bar` with `col` not equal to x, whereas mine will have a row with only `foo`s present.

Comment: No, sorry, your answer still excludes rows where a `foos` row is associated with one or more with bars rows all having col <> x. The total number of `foos` in your result will be different.

Comment: I would try joins together with includes than

Comment: When you specify a join with SQL, ActiveRecord applies the join when finding `foos`, but then finds `bars` using `WHERE id IN (1,2,3,....)` with no extra conditions.

Comment: @user1158559 , yes you're right but it use bars.ids from result of first query

Comment: Dude, the whole point of this question is to be able to specify an arbitrary condition on the second query.

Comment: Or to force ActiveRecord to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with conditions that filter `bars` without restricting the `foos` that get returned.

Comment: ok, here is some comment about this from official manual "even though Active Record lets you specify conditions on the eager loaded associations just like joins, the recommended way is to use joins instead." 
So I believe that the only way to go is to use  the raw SQL in joins method. Also you can combine it with select method.

Comment: @Fivell can you get active record to convert a custom outer join into eager loaded records? You can do the LEFT OUTER JOIN (as in your last example) with extra conditions but you're still not getting eager loading.

Comment: @spike, I always use select method for this, maybe other way is doing it with arel but I can't give an example right now

Comment: You can use select to eager load a one-to-many relationship? How do you do this?

Comment: @spike, not relationship but all needed data, like here http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=40125