# Refining the inner join when using includes in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

How do I add a condition to the ON clause generated by `includes` in active record while retaining eager loading?

Let's say I have these classes:

```
class Car
   has_many :inspections
end

class Inspection
   belongs_to :car
end
```

Now I can do:

```
Car.includes(:inspections)

Select * from cars LEFT OUTER JOIN inspections ON cars.id = inspections.car_id
```

But I want to generate this sql:

```
Select * from cars LEFT OUTER JOIN inspections ON cars.id = inspections.car_id 
    AND inspections.month = '2013-04-01'
```

(this doesn't work):

```
Car.includes(:inspections).where("inspections.month = 2013-04-01")

Select * from cars LEFT OUTER JOIN inspections ON cars.id = inspections.car_id
    WHERE inspections.month = '2013-04-01'
```

Comment: I think I might have an answer but I need to understand what your target return objects/collections are, instead of just the query. I believe you are looking to return all Cars, no matter what, but only related Inspections with the appropriate date.

Comment: It should be an ActiveRecord::Relation of all `Car` objects. Calling `inspections` on any of the `Cars` in the result set should return (eager loaded) all inspections for that car where month = 2013-04-01.

Comment: Thank you: please see my prospective solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've rethought your question more broadly. I think you are facing a code design problem as well as (instead of?) an ActiveRecord query problem.

You are asking to return a relation of Cars on which `.inspections` has been redefined to mean those Inspections matching a specific date. ActiveRecord does not allow you to redefine a model association on the fly, based on a query.

If you were not asking for a dynamic condition on the inspection date, I would tell you to use a `has_many :through` with a `:condition`.

```
has_many :passed_inspections, :through => :inspections, :conditions => {:passed => true}

@cars = Cars.includes(:passed_inspections)
```

Obviously, that would not work if you need to supply an inspection date on the fly.

So, in the end, I would tell you to do something like this:

```
@cars = Cars.all
@inspections = Inspection.where(inspections: {month: '2013-04-01', car_id: @cars.pluck(:id)})
```

(Exact, best implementation of that `car_id` where condition is up to debate. And you'll then need to group the `@inspections` by `car_id` to get the right subset in a given moment.)

Alternately, in a production environment, you might be able to rely on some fairly good/clever ActiveRecord caching. I'm not certain of this.

```
def inspections_dated(month)
  inspections.where(month: month)
end
Car.includes(:inspections).each{|car| car.inspections_dated(month).each.etc. }
```

**Alternately, Alternately**

You can, through manual SQL, trick ActiveRecord into giving you extended Car objects with an unclear interface:

```
@cars_with_insp = Car.join("LEFT OUTER JOIN inspections ON inspections.car_id = cars.id AND inspections.month = '2013-04-01'").select("cars.*, inspections.*")
@cars_with_insp.each{|c| puts c.name; puts c.inspection_month}
```

You'll see, in that `.each`, that you have the inspection's attributes available directly on `car`, because you've convinced ActiveRecord with a join to return two records of one class as a single row. Rails will tell you its class is Car, but it's more than a Car. You'll either get each Car once, for no matching Inspections, or multiple times for each matching Inspection.

Comment: Certainly, if you don't care about in-Ruby execution time, and just want to avoid N+1 queries, you could `car.inspections.select{|inspection| inspection.month == inspection_date}` once you've eager loaded via `Car.includes(:inspections)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You're right in the general case, but for the sake of this question I want to know if it's possible to do exactly what I asked. Your suggestion has the problem that it hits the database twice, and the second call has this potentially giant `in ()` statement attached. I'm really looking to learn more about the innards of ActiveRecord and how you'd go about converting the result set of an outer join into eager loaded-ness. Let's not get into an argument about the design decisions of my mock example.

Comment: Okay, got it. First concrete answer: ActiveRecord does not allow you to accomplish what you wish, which is to redefine `car.inspections` as the result of query parameters.

Comment: I added a final possible solution using a hard-coded join. And I removed my dogmatic discussion on your approach. Sorry.

Comment: I know you can add arbitrary columns to your select statement and have them show up as attributes. What I don't know is how to do magic with ActiveRecord to instantiate actual objects from the results. It should be possible to instantiate a full `Inspection` object from your query (since you're doing `select inspections.*`). How does the plumbing really work?

Comment: Apologies if it seems like my question is sprawling, but I think these are all facets of the same thing - how do I go from query results to full rails objects.

Comment: This is vague, but here goes. You can follow the ActiveRecord::Relation.exec_queries interplay with ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader to see how results from find_by_sql get stuffed into memory. But, you also need to look at how the collection association reader is defined in ActiveRecord::Associations to understand when Rails will go back to the database. Methods to consider include stale_target?, loaded!, and ...::Preloader::CollectionAssociation.preload.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this exactly, but what you are trying to do is probably not recommended *i.e.* violates one of Rails' conventions. According to this [answer in a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246826/how-do-i-avoid-multiple-queries-with-include-in-rails), the default behavior for such queries is to use two queries, like:

```
SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars";
SELECT "inspections".* FROM "inspections" WHERE "inspections"."car_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

This decision was made for performance reasons. That makes me guess that the exact type of query (JOIN or multiple queries) is an implementation detail that you cannot count on. Going along this train of thought, ActiveRecord::Relation probably wasn't designed for your use case, there is probably no way to add an `ON` condition in the query.

Going along this sequence of guesses, if you truly believe that your use case is unique, the best thing to do is probably for you to craft your own SQL query as follows:

```
Car.joins(sanitize_sql_array(["LEFT OUTER JOIN inspections ON inspections.car_id = cars.id AND inspections.month = ?", "2013-04-01"])
```

(Update: this was [asked last year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307685/activerecord-adding-condition-to-on-clause-for-includes?rq=1) and did not receive a good answer.)

### Alternative 1

As Carlos Drew suggested,

```
@cars   = Cars.all
car_ids = @cars.map(&:id) 
@inspections = Inspection.where(inspections: {month: '2013-04-01', car_id: car_ids})
# with scopes: Inspection.for_month('2013-04-01').where(car_id: car_ids)
```

However, in order to prevent `car.inspections` from triggering unnecessary SQL calls, you also need to do

```
# app/models/car.rb
has_many :inspections, inverse_of: :car

# app/models/inspection.rb
belongs_to :car, inverse_of: :inspections
```

### Alternative 2

Perhaps you can find a way to cache the inspections for the current month, and then don't worry about eager loading. This might be the best solution, since the cache can be reused in various places.

```
@cars = Cars.all
@cars.each do |car|
  car.inspections.where(month: '2013-04-01')
end
```

Comment: Ok, I think you and Carlos are correct, this can't be done in standard ActiveRecord. I also think I was overestimating the performance difference impact of large `IN()` statements vs joins (they still feel a little icky to me, but only seem 30-40% slower in some random testing). Using a second explicit statement is certainly cleaner to read.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Car.includes(:inspections).where( inspections: { month: '2013-04-01' })
```

Comment: Doesn't that do the same thing as my (now updated, but same result as before) last query?

Comment: Your answer adds to the `WHERE` clause, which is semantically different from adding to the `ON` clause.

Comment: Yeah that's basically the same as your update, sorry I didn't see that.

Comment: I was making up the code during my question. The typo was in the code, not the output sql.

Answer (score 0):

The authors of Rails did not build this functionality into ActiveRecord, presumably because using WHERE returns the same result set, and they felt no need to have an alternative.

In the docs and code, we find the two "official" methods of adding conditions to included models.

In the actual source code: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5245648812733d2c31f251de3e05e78e68bfa3a5/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb we find them using WHERE to accomplish this:

And I quote: "

## === conditions

```
#
# If you want to add conditions to your included models you'll have
# to explicitly reference them. For example:
#
# User.includes(:posts).where('posts.name = ?', 'example')
#
# Will throw an error, but this will work:
#
# User.includes(:posts).where('posts.name = ?', 'example').references(:posts)
```

_END_QUOTE_

The docs mention another approach: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html under the header "Eager loading of associations"

QUOTE:

If you do want eager load only some members of an association it is usually more natural to include an association which has conditions defined on it:

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :approved_comments, -> { where approved: true }, class_name: 'Comment'
end

Post.includes(:approved_comments)

This will load posts and eager load the approved_comments association, which contains only those comments that have been approved.

END QUOTE

You can technically use such an approach, but it in your case it may not be so useful if you are using dynamic month values.

These are the only options, which in any case return the same results as your AND based query.

Comment: I don't think this is right. It adds a WHERE condition, not a ON condition, which is semantically different.

Comment: I'm still confused about this. Like @JimLim notes, adding a condition to the where clause is not the same thing as a condition to the inner join.

Comment: The includes creates an outer join, (I think you made a typo in your comment), and the entire point of an outer join is that it includes, in your example, *all* cars no matter whether there are inspections to be joined with them. So adding a where clause in an outer join, by definition, will just limit the inspections, and not the cars.

Comment: Just so we're on the same page: We both agree that `"SELECT * from cars LEFT OUTER JOIN inspections on inspections.car_id = cars.id where month = '2013-04-01'` and `"SELECT * from cars LEFT OUTER JOIN inspections on inspections.car_id = cars.id and inspections.month = '2013-04-01'` are different things, correct?

Comment: The database engine may or may not process them differently under the hood, but they will both return the exact same results. That is, all cars, and all inspections with the month of '2013-04-01'. If you disagree, please explain.