# Advance query in rails especially with condition on associated/joined table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, active-record-query

I have seen looking everywhere for a solution and many time feeling that this is what I was looking for only to learn I need to keep looking so finally here it is...

I have a model **Person**:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base


  has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :inverse_of => :sender
  has_many :received_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :inverse_of => :receiver

  # ... ... ... 

end
```

And a model **Message**

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base


  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'Person', foreign_key => 'sender_id'
  belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => 'Person', foreign_key => 'receiver_id'

  # ... ... ...

end
```

Now I have to search the messages table for the **input** in search field for all those messages whose message **body**(it is a *column* in **messages** table for `Message` model  which contain only text) matches with input search string or with **last_name**(in sender of message, *last_name* is column in **people** table for `Person` model) of sender. I tried various ways but nothing worked and when I saw this [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) I thought this is it. This is what I have been looking for but alas this too rejected me and spewed an error, which is listed with query.

```
@messages = Message.includes(:sender).
                    where("UPPER(body) like UPPER(?) or 
                    UPPER(sender.last_name) like UPPER(?)", 
                    "%#{"sus"}%", "%#{"sus"}%").
                    references(:people)
```

In `references` i gave <:people> as given link suggested to give the name of actual table although I tried <:sender> as well that didn't work as expected.
The above query in `irb` console gave following error:-

```
undefined method `references' ActiveRecord::Relation
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table
```

I even tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454204/ruby-on-rails-add-condition-on-include-to-load-limited-number-of-objects) of *stackoverflow* but this didn't work as well.

So, please help me out here... What am I missing??

Note:-  I am using **PostgreSQL** for my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're having trouble. Does the below produce an error? Do you just want to check `sender.last_name` and not `receiver.last_name`, too?

```
Message.includes(:sender)
       .where("UPPER(body) LIKE UPPER(?) OR 
               UPPER(people.last_name) LIKE UPPER(?)", 
               "%#{"sus"}%", "%#{"sus"}%")
```

Couple of notes. I've used `senderS` (plural). If that doesn't work, find out what alias is being used on `includes(:sender)` using `Message.includes(:sender).to_sql`.

I Have no idea what `%#{"sus"}%` is (could you explain?), and `LIKE %%` is a very expensive query. Look into full-text search with postgres.

Comment: I am not checking for receicver.last_name because if I can get one correct then I can check with any of the attribute of people table. **%#{"sus"}%** is just to check if the checking attribute have this in it's content or not although I should have this as **%#{search_param}%**.  I ran `Message.includes(:sender).to_sql` and got  `"SELECT \"messages\".* FROM \"messages\" " ` while  running `Message.joins(:sender).where("UPPER(body) like UPPER(?) or UPPER(body) like UPPER(?) or UPPER(sender.first_name) like UPPER(?)", "%#{"sus"}%", search_key, search_key).to_sql` gave me

Comment: -gave me... `"SELECT \"messages\".* FROM \"messages\" INNER JOIN \"people\" ON \"people\".\"id\" = \"messages\".\"sender_id\" WHERE (UPPER(body) like UPPER('%sus%') or UPPER(body) like UPPER('%sus%') or UPPER(sender.first_name) like UPPER('%sus%'))"` . And running this query(after stripping <.to_sql>) is giving `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "sender"
LINE 1: ...us%') or UPPER(body) like UPPER('%sus%') or UPPER(sender.fir.. ` this error. I don't understand??? is the problem is due to **postgres** or what???. Let me know if you do not get any part of the Q?.

Comment: @zeal in that case, this should work `UPPER(people.last_name)`. It's because your table is called `people` and when dropping to SQL, you have to be explicit about the naming. Using `references(:people)` wouldn't work because you've already hard-coded `sender.last_name` into the SQL query. That only works when using AR query methods.

Comment: What you said is correct(using `UPPER(people.last_name)` in place of `UPPER(sender.last_name)`) worked; but I had to remove `references(:people)` as this was still generating `undefined method 'references' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xc65d34c>` error. Anyway thanks a lot. Finally I have some answer and please do comment on the error I am still getting. I will post an answer once every ambiguity clears off.

Comment: I have new problem here. Suppose message <has_and_belongs_to_many :receivers> through join table but now since a message belongs to many receivers so `UPPER(people.last_name)` gives result empty not that it results in error as now there is no unique last_name for a message. That's what is troubling me please comment. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry man, for the trouble it works at it is. I problem was I forgot to put them in reg-ex like expression "%<searching_string>%". Once again sorry and thanks.